# Restrict number of decimal places to two in Python float operations

Tags: python, floating-point, decimal

My idea is accept a number as input, perhaps `1.00` and then multiply it by a constant.

Subsequently it is passed to a function that determines whether or not it is a valid palindrome.

In the case that it is not, the number will be incrementally augmented until a valid palindrome is achieved-- however, I'd like to restrict the exploration space to the 2nd decimal place.

That is to say `1.01` is valid output, but `1.001` is not.

The code that follows executes the process described above, with the caveat that the current output is typically invalid, overflowing into smaller decimal spaces, i.e. `1.00001` and so on.

How can the number of decimal places of the operation be restricted to two?

```
import sys

# This method determines whether or not the number is a Palindrome
def isPalindrome(x):
    x = str(x).replace('.','')
    a, z = 0, len(x) - 1
    while a < z:
        if x[a] != x[z]:
            return False
        a += 1
        z -= 1
    return True

if '__main__' == __name__:

    trial = float(sys.argv[1])

    candidrome = trial + (trial * 0.15)

    print(candidrome)

    # check whether we have a Palindrome
    while not isPalindrome(candidrome):
        candidrome += 0.01

    if isPalindrome(candidrome):
        print( "It's a Palindrome! " + str(candidrome) )
```

The solution suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/455612/limiting-floats-to-two-decimal-points) does not seem to work:

```
# check whether we have a Palindrome
while not isPalindrome(format(round(candidrome,2))):
    candidrome += 0.01
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Limiting floats to two decimal points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/455612/limiting-floats-to-two-decimal-points)

Comment: so- I tried that solution- I reference it in the OP

Comment: Can you please print and post the number in the while loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it like this:

```
import sys

# This method determines whether or not the number is a Palindrome
def isPalindrome(x):
    x = str(x).replace('.','')
    a, z = 0, len(x) - 1
    while a < z:
        if x[a] != x[z]:
            return False
        a += 1
        z -= 1
    return True

if '__main__' == __name__:

    trial = float(sys.argv[1])

    candidrome = trial + (trial * 0.15)

    print(candidrome)
    candidrome = round(candidrome, 2)


    # check whether we have a Palindrome
    while not isPalindrome(candidrome):
        candidrome += 0.01
        candidrome = round(candidrome, 2)
        print(candidrome)

    if isPalindrome(candidrome):
        print( "It's a Palindrome! " + str(candidrome) )
```