# Search positive and negative space for second decimal point float palindrome operation in Python

Tags: python, floating-point, palindrome

This code takes a float as input, for instance a number like `1.01`, then it multiplies it by a constant.

Subsequently it seeks out the closest numerical palindrome to that number.

**However**

At this point it only searches in one direction, it only increments the number-- what I'm trying to do is to get it to search in the positive direction and the negative direction simultaneously (*(or at least in quick succession*).

Checkout the way it works now, maybe a bit naive:

```
import sys

# This method determines whether or not the number is a Palindrome
def isPalindrome(x):
    x = str(x).replace('.','')
    a, z = 0, len(x) - 1
    while a < z:
        if x[a] != x[z]:
            return False
        a += 1
        z -= 1
    return True

if '__main__' == __name__:

    trial = float(sys.argv[1])

    candidrome = trial + (trial * 0.15)

    print(candidrome)
    candidrome = round(candidrome, 2)


    # check whether we have a Palindrome
    while not isPalindrome(candidrome):
        candidrome += 0.01
        candidrome = round(candidrome, 2)
        print(candidrome)

    if isPalindrome(candidrome):
        print( "It's a Palindrome! " + str(candidrome) )
```

I've been attempting to insert these functions somewhere into my loop:

```
def incrementer(candidrome):
    candidrome += 0.01
    candidrome = round(candidrome, 2)
    return candidrome

def decrementer(candidrome):
    candidrome -= 0.01
    candidrome = round(candidrome, 2)
    return candidrome
```

But I've not been able to pin it down yet. How to exhaustively search the positive and negative space for the *closest* (in numberline distance) numerical palindrome?

Comment: The code is the same [as in your prior question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46374858/restrict-number-of-decimal-places-to-two-in-python-float-operations). Is this a duplicate? It seems that they are essentially trying to solve the same problem.